# Git stash not applying all my changes

Tags: git, github

I am working on a group project. I made a bunch of changes to my files and right before I pushed to gitHub I noticed there had been a new update so I ran the commands

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git stash
```

then I updated with github

```
git pull
```

I changed a gem file and two other places that called for the gem 'rmagick' because it causes me issues.

Then I ran the command

```
git stash pop
```

It asked me to commit the changed files and I did,

I ran the git stash pop again but not all of my updates came back. Please help me so I do not lose 3 hours work.

When I run `git stash show -p` I can see all of my changes! I think ....

THANKS!!!!!!

I ran the following commands to fix it....

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git stash pop 
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
```

Comment: `gitk --all` are all your changes already commited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git stash
```

At this point **nothing** is stashed, since `stash` only handles uncommitted work.

Answer (score 0):

Staging with `git add .` add all files from the `pwd` recursively. Followed by `git commit`, all changes will have been committed in your first run.

Your `git stash pop` likely popped something else off your stash stack and resulted in the possible confusion. `pop`ing applies the stashed changes and drops it from the stash stack.

To see what is in your stash:

`git stash list`

To see the contents of any stash, grab the stash shorthand of `stash@{<n>}` and run this:

`git show <stash-shorthand>`